# How can I download the latest ringtones?

Tags: ringtone

How can I download the latest ringtones?

Comment: We don't handle shopping questions or app recommendations, sorry.  We're focused on solving specific Android problems -- for example, "My selected ringtone doesn't play when I receive a call, how can I fix this?"  Please see the [FAQ].

Answer (score 4):

I'd highly suggest [Zedge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zedge.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC56ZWRnZS5hbmRyb2lkIl0.) for awesome ringtones! Everyone in my family has been using it for quite a while, and finding some pretty sweet stuff :)

They have **ringtones** in the following categories:

```
All Categories
Alternative
Blues
Bollywood
Children
Christian & Gospel
Classical
Comedy
Country
Dance
Electronica
Entertainment
Games
Hip Hop
Holiday
Jazz
Latin
Message Tones
News & Politics
Other
Pets & Animals
Pop
R&B/Soul
Reggae
Rock
Sayings
Sound Effects
World
```

Comment: I like http://audiko.net if you don't want to install an app.